# How to simulate movement of rollers

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

How can a simulation smoothly reproduce the movement of a box on a conveyor. The model described below will simulate the movement, but as the box moves from roller to roller, the box jumps and the rollers do not behave smoothly.

[image]

What solver settings or model setup will improve the simulation.

Details:

1. The rollers were added by creating cylinder meshes. Each cylinder was setup as a rigid-body simulation with mesh collision shape.
2. The box was added as a cube that is subdivided several times. The box is setup as a rigid-body simulation with mesh collision shape.
3. The simulation was run, with the results shown in the animation above.

How can this simulation be made to behave more realistically?

The Blender files with this simulation is here - [image]

This question is based on trying to answer this question - [Animate Individual Vertices w/ Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240879/animate-individual-vertices-w-geometry-nodes) - using simulation rather than animation nodes.

---

Per the accepted answer, changing the collision shape to box fixed the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just change the shape to Box and it looks really smooth

[image]

[image]

Comment: Might be a good idea to change the rollers to cylinder or capsule as well.

Comment: What was it before, if not box?

Comment: It was mesh before

Comment: That worked great! Is there a reason why the mesh had issue but using a box fixed it? It seems like they should get the same result.

Comment: I think they can but then you have to mess around with all the settings in there…the Box makes it easier for Blender to calculate. That’s why it „seems“ to be more stable.